# Can I re-pitch a cast iron waste pipe without cracking it?

Tags: plumbing, cast-iron, old-pipes

Bought my first house last year. 1957 single story ranch. Inspector missed this, but i noticed early on that this pipe hanger had come loose (and been poorly resecured) causing a ~6 foot run of the waste pipe to pitch slightly in the wrong direction.

Everything was draining fine and nothing was leaking when we moved in so I left it that way for a while. Recently had a clog in the bathroom sink and had to snake all the way down to this sagging joint to clear it, so probably time to do something about it if I can.

My thinking is to use a bottle jack and a 2x4 to slowly jack up the sagging joint and secure it with a sturdier strap. Probably don't have the space to get it to 1/4" per foot, but should at least be able to get it sloping in the right direction. The branch lines flowing into that run have some extra slope to them, so I don't think it will cause an upstream issue.

Mostly worried about cracking the cast iron. The pipes are almost 70 years old, so I'm aware that this would be a temporary fix at best, but I aim to get as many years as I can out of the current plumbing before considering replacement. If there's an obviously better solution, I'm all for it.

[image: sagging joint]

[image: run of pipe]

[image: bad pitch, Bad!]

Comment: Good cast usually needs a sharp hit to crack.  Gentle slow lifting should be okay.  70 year old cast might have weak spots.

Comment: Not writing this as an answer, b/c plumbing isn’t my specialty, but think of it this way: if you move it and it doesn’t leak, you win. If you move it and it leaks, all you need to do is cut out the leaky section and throw some abs in there.